Детский вопрос о «еде для волос»
Девочка (12 лет) обратила мое внимание на рекламу средства для волос (на "Пятом канале").
Не знаю, что за средство. На флаконе я успела увидеть только такие слова:
             ЕДА для 
             ВОЛОС  

Нашелся и сайт с этой продукцией: Чем баловать свои волосы? Hair Food или «Еда для волос».
Девочка поинтересовалась: можно ли так говорить, грамотно ли?
(Я сказала, что мне НЕ нравится, но объяснить своё неприятие не смогла.)
А как вам, друзья, видится — всё ли хорошо в названии?

Поздравляем с Новым годом! Всем-всем — хорошего настроения!

Присоединяюсь с поздравлениям!

Конечно, фраза " Еда для волос" стилистически неудачна. Поскольку еда -  Пищевой продукт, кушанье, что-л. используемое в качестве пищи, имеющее определенный вкус, питательную ценность и необходимое для жизнедеятельности человека, животного или живого существа, приготовленное каким-л. образом или употребляемое в пищу в сыром виде в качестве первого, второго блюда, сладкого блюда или закуски (Большой толковый словарь).
Это  маркетинговый ход, пиар, нацеленный на привлечения внимания. И здесь понятно, что использована метафора( причем неудачная), которой хотели сказать, что данное средство имеет питательные  свойства. Маркетологи часто к таким манипуляциям текстам, часто в ущерб к языку. Здесь они наделяют волосы живыми свойствами, что вызывает смущения.
Конечно, можно бы придумать варианты удачнее.
Инновационное питание для волос.
Эликсир здоровья для волос
Формула сияния.
Этот список можно продолжать.
